# Android Dynamically Create and Place MapView

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, android-mapview

I am currently working on an app for Android and cannot seem to figure this out.  My screen, which is currently just one big `SurfaceView`, is separated into 4 quadrants (not really, its all still one `SurfaceView` on one thread).

I am trying to dynamically allocate a `MapView` and display it in the top right quadrant of my screen while still having it redraw itself to update the current position.  Are there any suggestions on how to do this?  Is there a way to put it on a layer on top, make the layer transparent, then Offset the `MapView` to the top right?  Or maybe making a layer on the top right hand quadrant and have it display the `MapView`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.  Created a RelativeLayout that covered the screen, then created another RelativeLayout in that one and aligned it to the top-right and modified the height and width.  Dynamically allocated the SurfaceView onto the RelativeLayout that fills the screen, then dynamically allocated the MapView onto the RelativeLayout at the top right.